# Why do I get a warning about the verification code of my RSK Testnet address?

Tags: rsk

I have connected my web3 instance to the public testnet of RSK and after creating my wallet using `rsk.accounts.wallet.create(1, entropy)` and receiving some tRBTC from the faucet, I get the following when I go on the [RSK Testnet Explorer](https://explorer.testnet.rsk.co/).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you see what you see in the screenshot is due to the checksum. RSK uses [EIP-1191](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md) for checksums, which means that the combination of lower-cased and upper-cased letters in the address is different from that of what would would get when using a library that uses [EIP-55](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md).

So, what can you do about this?

(1) Use a different software library that supports EIP-1191. Be sure to pass in the `chainId` (`30` for RSK Mainnet, `31` for RSK Testnet), otherwise the checksum will be the same as an EIP-55 one.

(2) Use a workaround, to ignore/ bypass checksum verification on your address. You can switch to all lower-case or all upper-case in order to do so. Note that this explicitly skips verification in both EIP-55 and EIP-1191.

---

Edit to add more detail:

Here's the reference material regarding checksums on RSK: https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/architecture/account-based/#checksum

If the purpose is to check if you can actually use the this address,
the best thing to do would be to check that you can sign messages
with the private key linked to this address.
There are 2 common ways to do this:

(1) **On-chain**: Sign a transaction. Send a nominal amount of RBTC to another EOA or an SC. This will incur gas fees, of course.

(2) **Off-chain**: Sign an arbitrary text message.

- You can do so programmatically using `eth_sign`,
  for example [`signer.signMessage` in ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Signer-signMessage)
- If do not wish to do so programmatically,
  and instead use a DApp and browser wallet,
  follow these [instructions on how to verify address ownership on RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/kb/verify-address-ownership/)